# Is there a way to use a script to copy/paste from a google doc?

Tags: javascript, python, google-apps-script, google-docs-api

**Info:**

I have a google doc with a list of emails, separated by newlines like such:

```
Email1@gmail.com
Email2@gmail.com
Email3@gmail.com
...
```

Ideally, I would like to, from the gmail that owns the doc, be able to run a script that copies all of the emails in the doc directly into a gmail recipients tab when I want to compose an email to that list of people.

I am aware there are probably other ways to do a similar thing, for example, printing out the contents to a terminal or something of the like. I would prefer to use the Google Docs API, but am open to ways that are outside of that. Edit: Copying the text to a clipboard would also be acceptable, I just have no idea how to do that.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Also, if I've left out key information please let me know!

**Current Code in Google Apps Script (Google Docs API):**

```
function grabText() {
  const documentID = 'mydocumentid';
  return DocumentApp.openById(documentID).getBody().getText().split(/\n/).join(',');
}
```

Comment: what have you tried so far? are you stuck on getting started with the Google Docs API? https://developers.google.com/docs/api/quickstart/python

Comment: The latter exactly, I'm just having a rough start understanding how to work with the API.

Comment: where are you stuck? what is the output of your current code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Paste the script into the script editor of the  document you wish it to access.  It will return a string of comma separated emails that you can paste into your email script.

I added the Logger.log() so that you can see the recipients for testing.

```
function getEmails() {
  const recipients = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody().getText().split(/\n/).join(',');
  Logger.log(recipients)
  return recipients
}
```

Comment: Apologies for my unfamiliarity with the google docs API, but how does this access the specific document I want? And does it copy to the clipboard?

I'll update the question with my current code.

Comment: DocumenrtApp.getActiveDocument() gets the current container.  No clipboard copy.  It returns the string to whatever calls it.  like `Gmail.sendEmail(getEmails(),.....)`

Answer (score 0):

Does it need to by python or JavaScript? What I would do, is run an [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) script like this:

```
Sleep, 3000
Send, email1@gmail.com email2@gmail.com email3@gmail.com
```

In order to get these emails in a list this way, you can copy-paste the google docs with all the emails into VScode (or another text editor with support for Replace All), select a newline character (by dragging your most from the start of line 2 to the end of line 1, for example), and replacing all newlines with a space. The sleep, 3000 is there so that you have 3 seconds between when you run the AHK script and you move your mouse over to the mail recipient text box.